epub.js always empty in web page
I'm struggling trying to get a epub file to display in a web page using epub.js. I've seen all the examples, and documentation but I can't get an epub to appear. I have this HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <style>
    #area {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      position: absolute;
      left: 50px;
      top: 10px;
      width: 600px;
      height: 400px;
      border: 1px dotted red;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="epub.js"></script>
  <script src="jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    window.onload = function () {
      let book = ePub('epub/house.epub'),
          rendition = book.renderTo('area',
            {
              openAs: 'epub',
              method: 'default',
              width:  '100%',
              height: 400
            }
          ),
          displayed = rendition.display();
    };
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="area"></div>
</body>

</html>

and running it in a browser from VS Code I get this in the network panel:

So while everything appears to load, and no errors display in the console, I keep getting an empty #area.
What am I missing? Or is there a basic example I can download that does work that I can check?

I tested some other epub files I have and it works with them. I'm unsure what's "wrong" with house.epub as it displays fine in the reader calibre and unzips into valid looking files.
